# Echo tab characters in bash script

Tags: bash, tabs, echo, spaces

How do I echo one or more tab characters using a bash script?
When I run this code

```
res='       'x # res = "\t\tx"
echo '['$res']' # expect [\t\tx]
```

I get this

```
res=[ x] # that is [<space>x]
```

Answer (score 757, accepted):

```
echo -e ' \t '
```

will echo 'space tab space newline' (`-e` means 'enable interpretation of backslash escapes'):

```
$ echo -e ' \t ' | hexdump -C
00000000  20 09 20 0a                                       | . .|
```

Comment: Thanks Johannes. You helped me find this solution : res='\t\t'x; echo -e '['$res']'

Comment: Do you happen to know, why `echo -e` does not work from Makefiles?

Comment: That's because `echo -e` is not POSIX and `make` calls `/bin/sh` which is normally not the program use use interactively, and normally hasn't `-e` implemented. For portability, use `printf '\t'` instead.

Comment: In Darwin (macOS), the `man` page for the `echo` command does not mention the option `-e`. However, this option is accepted.

Answer (score 95):

Use `printf`, not `echo`.

There are multiple different versions of the `echo` command.  There's `/bin/echo` (which may or may not be the GNU Coreutils version, depending on the system), and the `echo` command is built into most shells.  Different versions have different ways (or no way) to specify or disable escapes for control characters.

`printf`, on the other hand, has much less variation.  It can exist as a command, typically `/bin/printf`, and it's built into some shells (bash and zsh have it, tcsh and ksh don't), but the various versions are much more similar to each other than the different versions of `echo` are.  And you don't have to remember command-line options (with a few exceptions; GNU Coreutils printf accepts `--version` and `--help`, and the built-in bash printf accepts `-v var` to store the output in a variable).

For your example:

```
res='           'x # res = "\t\tx"
printf '%s\n' "[$res]"
```

And now it's time for me to admit that `echo` will work just as well for the example you're asking about; you just need to put double quotes around the argument:

```
echo "[$res]"
```

as kmkaplan wrote (two and a half years ago, I just noticed!).  The problem with your original commands:

```
res='           'x # res = "\t\tx"
echo '['$res']' # expect [\t\tx]
```

isn't with `echo`; it's that the shell replaced the tab with a space before `echo` ever saw it.

`echo` is fine for simple output, like `echo hello world`, but you should use `printf` whenever you want to do something more complex.  You *can* get `echo` to work, but the resulting code is likely to fail when you run it with a different `echo` implementation or a different shell.

Comment: I liked this one, it allows me to use the knowledge of printf and all the format specifiers.

Comment: @JezenThomas: It is not more upvoted because it answers the question in another way than requested. The question specifically mentions echo, and echo is not a verb but a command.

Comment: @PauloNeves: I'd say it's used as a verb in the question: "How do I **echo** one or more tab characters using a bash script?"

Answer (score 75):

You can also try:

```
echo Hello$'\t'world.
```

Comment: +1 for more general solution.  I've been using bash for years and I just learned this now!

Comment: This is a much more general than the accepted answer as it can be used without echo.

Comment: This also seems to work: `$'Hello\tWorld'`

Answer (score 36):

Put your string between **double** quotes:

```
echo "[$res]"
```

Comment: same here - this is what I tried first. -e worked fine though

Comment: @kmkaplan  Works for me in zsh - fails for me in bash

Answer (score 28):

you need to use  -e flag for echo then you can

```
echo -e "\t\t x"
```

Answer (score 27):

From the bash man page:

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

So you can do this:

```
echo $'hello\tworld'
```

Comment: Why does this work on the cli but not in a bash script?

Comment: @Freek It works for me — maybe post your script where it doesn't work as a separate question?

Answer (score 20):

Use the verbatim keystroke, `^V` (`CTRL+V`, `C-v`, *whatever*).

When you type `^V` into the terminal (or in most Unix editors), the following character is taken *verbatim*.  You can use this to type a literal tab character inside a string you are echoing.

Something like the following works:

```
echo "^V<tab>"     # CTRL+V, TAB
```

[Bash docs](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_7.html#SEC54) (*q.v.*, "quoted-insert")

> quoted-insert (C-q, C-v)
>   Add the next character that you type to the line verbatim. This is how to insert key sequences like C-q, for example.

*side note: according to this,* `ALT+TAB` *should do the same thing, but we've all bound that sequence to window switching so we can't use it*

> tab-insert (M-TAB)
>   Insert a tab character.

--

Note: you can use this strategy with all sorts of unusual characters.  Like a carriage return:

```
echo "^V^M"        # CTRL+V, CTRL+M
```

This is because carriage return is ASCII 13, and **M** is the 13th letter of the alphabet, so when you type `^M`, you get the 13th ASCII character.  You can see it in action using `ls^M`, at an empty prompt, which will insert a carriage return, causing the prompt to act just like you hit return.  When these characters are normally interpreted, *verbatim* gets you get the literal character.

Comment: Wish I could give you more upvotes for this one.  I didn't want to use a -e in my arguments in this case, and this works great.  Thanks!

Comment: "... most Unix editors"? Tried to enter this with both vi and emacs and it didn't give the desired results in either.

Comment: That's soooo cool! And saved my day when trying to use `grep` for catching lines containing `tab` characters.

Comment: `echo "somthing^V<tab>something" > file` outputs the text exactly as is to the file :-/

Answer (score 12):

Using echo to print values of variables is a common Bash pitfall.
Reference link:

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo

Comment: Cool, I like the "BashPitfalls", great piece of material and ease a lot of pain from my daily work!

Comment: +1 because this is sooo true. But note that kalyanji string starts with a “[” and does not contain any “\”.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `echo "a\tb"` in a script, you run the script as:

```
# sh -e myscript.sh
```

Alternatively, you can give to myscript.sh the execution permission, and then run the script.

```
# chmod +x myscript.sh
# ./myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res="\t\tx"
echo -e "[${res}]"
```