# Concatenate output of two commands into one line

Tags: bash, shell, concatenation

I have a very basic shell script here:

```
for file in Alt_moabit Book_arrival Door_flowers Leaving_laptop
do
    for qp in 10 12 15 19 22 25 32 39 45 60
    do
        for i in 0 1
        do
            echo "$file\t$qp\t$i" >> psnr.txt
            ./command > $file-$qp-psnr.txt 2>> psnr.txt
        done
    done
done
```

`command` calculates some PSNR values and writes a detailed summary to a file for each combination of `file`, `qp` and `i`. That's fine.

The `2>>` outputs one line of information that I really need. But when executed, I get:

```
Alt_moabit  10  0
total   47,8221 50,6329 50,1031
Alt_moabit  10  1
total   47,8408 49,9973 49,8197
Alt_moabit  12  0
total   47,0665 50,1457 49,6755
Alt_moabit  12  1
total   47,1193 49,4284 49,3476
```

What I want, however, is this:

```
Alt_moabit  10  0    total  47,8221 50,6329 50,1031
Alt_moabit  10  1    total  47,8408 49,9973 49,8197
Alt_moabit  12  0    total  47,0665 50,1457 49,6755
Alt_moabit  12  1    total  47,1193 49,4284 49,3476
```

How can I achieve that?

(Please feel free to change the title if you think there's a more appropriate one)

Comment: Exactly what I needed today! Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The (GNU version of) echo utility has a -n option to omit the trailing newline. Use that on your first echo. You'll probably have to put some space after the first line or before the second for readability.

Answer (score 40):

You could pass the **`-n`** option to your first `echo` command, so it doesn't output a newline.

As a quick demonstration, this :

```
echo "test : " ; echo "blah"
```

will get you :

```
test : 
blah
```

With a newline between the two outputs.

While this, with a **`-n`** for the first `echo` :

```
echo -n "test : " ; echo "blah"
```

will get you the following output :

```
test : blah
```

Without any newline between the two output.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `printf` instead of `echo`, which is [better for portability reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8161194/3708977).

Answer (score 9):

printf is the correct way to solve your problem (+1 kurumi), but for completeness, you can also do:

```
   echo "$file\t$qp\t$i $( ./command 2>&1 > $file-$qp-psnr.txt )" >> psnr.txt
```

Comment: I guess there's no _correct_ way. drysam's solution worked for me and he was the first to answer. Thanks for this interesting one-liner though! :)

Comment: Maybe 'correct' is too strong, but printf will be more portable than echo -n.

Answer (score 0):

While `echo -n` may work if you just want the print the output to console, it won't work if you want the output redirected to file.

If you want the concatenated output to be redirected to a file, this will work:

```
echo "Str1: `echo "Str2"`" >> file
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem.
To define my problem, I have a script which is using the echo function like this:

```
echo -n "Some text here"
echo -n "Some text here"
```

The output I was getting is like this:

```
-n Some text here
-n Some text here
```

and I want the text to be in same line and it is also printing -n option in the output.

Note :- According to man Page, -n option do not print the trailing newline character.

The way I solved it using by adding the shebang in the starting of the script file like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Some text here"
echo -n "Some text here"
```

This will print the desired output like this:

```
Some text here Some text here
```

Hope this helps!