# Entering a <space> into a shell script in Ubuntu through echo

Tags: shell, ubuntu, echo, cjk

i was looking over the web for this but came up with nothing, i found this Q&A over stackoverflow [Echo tab characters in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525872/echo-spaces-in-bash-script)
but it didn't help me.

i have an index of about 9000 lines, each line has one or two letters in Chinese.

any way i would like to rewrite each line so it will be the same only with space in the end. for example:

in the original index : AB

in the new index : AB

this is the script i wrote but it didn't do the work it just put empty line after each item in the index, with no space, what am i missing???

this is the code tough:

```
 rm new_index.txt
 for line in $(cat index.txt)
   do
     echo "$line \t"  >> new_index.txt
   done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    printf '%s \n' "$line"
done < index.txt > new_index.txt
```

This will preserve each line exactly but will append a space before each newline.

Note: the `printf` is not special, you could also say

```
echo "$line "
```

and get the same effect. The important thing is how you read the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it with sed

```
sed -e 's/$/ /' index.txt > new_index.txt
```

You could also do it inplace i.e. update the same file

```
sed -e 's/$/ /' -i index.txt
```

With backup

```
sed -e 's/$/ /' -i.bak index.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Not bashy, but it's what sed is for!

```
sed 's/$/ \t/' index.txt > new_index.txt
```

As for bash, you should have a '-e' for the echo to make it understand that \t is a tab character instead of a backslash and a t.

```
rm new_index.txt
for line in $(cat index.txt)
  do
    echo -e "$line \t" >> new_index.txt
  done
```