# Format spaces in bash output with echo

Tags: bash, output

Im trying to have some symple output, the issue is that I can't seem to set the spaces. I have to manually calculate what each variable will have. Is there a way to format table outputs better with echo?

This code

```
      echo """
      Datasets available to download are:
    
      Dataset   -   File Format
      ${dataset_one[6]}    -   ${dataset_one[5]}
      ${dataset_two[6]}  -   ${dataset_two[5]}
      ${dataset_three[6]}    -   ${dataset_three[5]}
    
      You currently have downloaded to hdfs the the following datasets:
      """
```

Returns:

```
  Dataset   -   File Format
  dataset1   -   csv
  ds2  -   csv
  datasnytaxi   -   parquet
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `column -t` is what you are looking for:

> -t      Determine the number of columns the input contains and create a table.  Columns are delimited with whitespace, by default, or with the characters supplied using the -s option.  Useful for pretty-printing displays.

Answer (score 1):

Try using '\t' with echo command. you can also refer to [Echo tab characters in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525872/echo-tab-characters-in-bash-script) for how to use '\t' with echo in bash.
alternative you can also try printf;